# Google App Script used with Google Sheets onEdit() not triggering when specified cells are updated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script that takes in 2 dates (start and end date), creates new columns for each week between the two dates, then auto-fills the start of each week in the header of the new columns in a sheet called 'Timeline & Financials'. The function is called `nm()`.

I'm using the onEdit function to trigger the script when either the start (cell W1) or end date (cell X1) cell in 'Timeline & Financials' changes.

Users are not supposed to edit cells W1 or X1 manually. Those cells are linked to cells in another tab called 'Reousrce(s)' in the same spreadsheet via the function `=MIN('Resource(s)' !G2:G900)` and `=MAX('Reousrce(s)' !H2:H900)`
*To clarify, W1 and X1 in 'Timeline & Financials' contain the min and max function*

My goal is to have users edit the 'Resource(s)' tab which will change W1 or X1 in 'Timeline & Financials' then trigger the function that creates the columns.

My problem is finding a way for onEdit to recognize when a cell has been changed then trigger the script.

I found 2 solutions to specify which cells must be edited to trigger but each have issues:

Solution 1:

The function successfully triggers when W1 or X1 updates due a change in the 'Resource(s) sheet but it unintentionally runs the script when any cell in 'Timeline & Financials' is changed.

How can I limit the trigger to only W1 or X1 using this solution? Am I misunderstanding the use of `.getA1Notation()`?

Solution 2

The function will only successfully trigger if the user goes in and manually types in the dates in W1 or X1, not when 'Resource(s)' updates W1 or X1.

My guess is that this solution only checks the function in the cell (`=MIN('Resource(s)' !G2:G900)` and `=MAX('Reousrce(s)' !H2:H900)`) rather than the value in the cell (the actual dates)

Is there a way for script to look out an edit in value in a cell rather than a change of a function?

The code is below:

````
function onEdit(e){
  var template = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Timeline & Financials");
  var startDate = "V3"; 
  var endDate = "V4";

  // Solution 1
  // if (e.range.getA1Notation() == startDate || e.range.getA1Notation() == endDate ){
  //     console.log("in if");
  //     return;
  // } else {
    
  //   deleteColumns();
      
  //     nm();
  // }


 // Solution 2
 //  if (e.range.rowStart != 1 ||  !(e.range.columnStart >= 23 && e.range.columnStart <    25) ){
 //    console.log("in if");
 //    return;
 //   } else {
 // 
 //  deleteColumns();
 //    
 //  nm();
 //  }

} ```
````

Comment: See linked duplicate: set `requiredRange` to `G2:H900` and `requiredSheets` to `['Resource(s)']`

Comment: @TheMaster That would trigger the script every time cells in that range changes but I used '''=MIN('Resource(s)' !G2:G900)''' and '''=MAX('Reousrce(s)' !H2:H900)''' because I only want to trigger when the the earliest date or the latest date changes. If an edit in G2:H900 falls between the the current start and end date then I wouldn't want it to call the function

Comment: Shouldn't be hard from there: Check the value of W1 and X1 after  the edit in G2:H900. If it's different from previous, do the needful. You may need to store the previous max and min in properties service though. Regardless, reopened the question.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want, but what your script curently does is: Solution1: If the edited cell is `V3` or `V4` - log `in if`. If the cell is any other - run the function  `deleteColumns()` and `nm()`. Solution 2: If the row is not the first one and the column is not `X` or `Y` - log `in if`, in all other cases, run `deleteColumns()` and `nm()`. Both solutions work regardless of which sheet is being edited. Does it help you finding the problem? Maybe you are actually trying to do the opposite? Run your funcitons only if the edited cell is `V3` or `V4`?